# Websocket across pages JavaScript

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have implemented a basic websockets client in JS:

```
function connectToNotifServer(){

var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

conn.onopen = function(e) {
    alert("Connection established!");
    conn.send(JSON.stringify({user_id: sessionStorage.getItem("user_id")}));
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    alert(e.data);
};

conn.onclose = function(e) {
    alert("Connection closed!");
};
return conn;
}
```

But I want to use the websocket connection on a page. However, if I simply call this method on load, then I am concerned a new connection will be made each time the page is reloaded, is this a problem?. Is there anyway, to make a connection once and use that throughout different pages and page reloads?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by opening the WebSocket connection from a shared background Web worker.

The WebSocket connection will stay open when at least one tab is still active to the given origin (of the shared Web worker).

I know that Chrome and IE11 support opening WebSocket connections from dedicated Web workers. Firefox does not currently. I don't know which browsers support WebSocket connection from *shared* Web workers (which is what you'd need).

Comment: Nice, I didnt know you could do that

Answer (score 0):

This wont be any problem. Because every time when page will reload the page will loose the connection and will establish a new connection.

And the answer of your other question "Is there anyway, to make a connection once and use that throughout different pages and page reloads" is no. You can not use the same connection through out the page after page reload.

Answer (score 0):

You can't keep the connection opened if the user changes pages.