# Websocket: maintain user session after page reloading

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, websocket, single-page-application

I've got a simple Single Page Application using jetty websockets for communication between server and client.

***Problem:*** Each time I have reload page my websocket connection is disabled and new is initialized. The problem is that user should relogin on each page refresh.

***Question:*** *How can I eliminate the need of relogin on page refresh?*

***EDITED:*** Faced the next *problem*: how to decide when session should be deleted? I've a peer object on the server side which is a nothing else but websocket session container. Peer is deleted on `onClose` method, which in turn is invoked on droping client side websocket. Here the problem comes: when user press F5 -> client side websocket is broken -> server delete appropriate websocket -> client side try to reload a page and check if there is any session AND FIND NOTHING. On the other hand I can't cease removing y peers (sessions) at all.

*Question:* How can I tell server when to remove my peers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21675335/884770

Comment: @oberstet my application should support Chrome and Firefox. As I understand it's impossible at the moment. Am I right?

Comment: Firefox does not (yet) support opening WebSocket connections from Web workers (neither dedicated nor shared). So if Firefox is required, then "no, not possible". https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=504553

Comment: @oberstet see updated version of my question please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To eliminate the need to authenticate a WebSocket connection upon each new connection establishment you can use cookies.

Authenticate the WebSocket connection upon first time, set cookie *on the WebSocket connection*, and recheck the cookie upon a new connection.

This requires a WebSocket server that allows to read and set cookies on a WebSocket connection.

If the WebSocket connection is served from the same origin as the HTML page containing the JavaScript that opens the WebSocket connection, you could also use a "normal" HTML form based login plus cookie procedure:

1. User opens "login.html", which contains a HTML form for login
2. User enters username/password, which submits the HTML form via HTTP/POST to some URL
3. The server checks the credentials, and when successful, generates a random cookie, stores the cookie, and sets the cookie on the HTML page returned from the HTTP/POST
4. This latter returned page then opens a WebSocket connection to the server (which is on same origin, and hence the previously set cookie is set)
5. The WebSocket server in the opening handshake checks if there is a cookie, and if the cookie is stored in the DB for logged-in users
6. If so, the WebSocket connection succeeds. If not, the WebSocket server does not establish a connection, but redirects the user to 1.

Comment: @oderstet I am not sure if I understand you well. Do you mean that I should store credentials in cookies and than program relogin automatically?

Comment: Like with usual cookie login: upon successful first login, generate a random cookie, store the cookie in the backend, and upon reconnect, check if cookie is present. If so, auto-login.

Comment: Yes I've got only one origin. Can you explain the last paragraph in detail please. Or provide a little example.

Comment: Please see the edited answer. Should be enough to get you started. It's really a "standard login" mechanism (for which you can find tons of examples/variants) plus reusing the cookie on the WebSocket connection. "Reusing the cookie": as mentioned, this is only possible if you have the HTML form login and WebSocket on same origin.

Comment: @oberset see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782233/websockets-restore-session-on-page-reloading please. It's the next step of this issue.