# jQuery socket - 'An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable'

Tags: jquery, sockets

I'm trying to learn to use sockets. I did not find anything about this error, or I'm searching for the wrong keywords. Anyways, I can connect to my socket but when I'm trying to send a message I get this error:

> InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

```js
$('#send-btn').click(function(){ //use clicks message send button    
        var mymessage = $('#message').val(); //get message text
        var myname = $('#name').val(); //get user name

        if(myname == ""){ //empty name?
            alert("Enter your Name please!");
            return;
        }
        if(mymessage == ""){ //emtpy message?
            alert("Enter Some message Please!");
            return;
        }

        //prepare json data
        var msg = {
        message: mymessage,
        name: myname,
        color : '<?php echo $colours[$user_colour]; ?>'
        };
        //convert and send data to server
        websocket.send('hello');
});
```

I can't find any information about this error or I'm doing the same error again and searching for the wrong keywords. Anyway I hope some of you guys have an answer on what I can do instead or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you trying to use [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)?

Comment: I think so :P this is the connect line `websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); `

Comment: Could you maybe show a bit more code, such as in what context are you calling `.send()` ?

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/MAL4kQR5JFTtiJcwze7jSX - I paste the code there so you can see

Comment: seems to work fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/5jwotwg7/2/

Comment: Hmm im going to start over and hopefully it will work :P Thansk @M.Doye

Comment: No problem, here is another example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721263/websockets-not-working/32722113#32722113 - it could be a browser support issue

Comment: The link you shared with me on jsfiddle works, can it be my server.php that spokes?

Answer (score 3):

You call the `websocket.send()` function too fast.

You should call it when the websocket netstate is valid or ESTABLISHED.

You can try the call via `setTimeout` (the function that calls the `websocket.send` method and `time`).

Answer (score 1):

This is my case when my internet connection is interrupted to resolve this error you must send to socket when ready state is ok:

```
if (socket.readyState == 1) {
    socket.send ('bal bla'); 
}
```